# Can I buy songs from iTunes within my iPhone appplication?

Tags: iphone, itunes, development, ios

I'm new to iPhone development and sorry if my question sounds stupid. Just wondering is it possible that I can buy songs from the iTunes using my iPhone application I just saw some apps doing the same.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, no you can't. Buying music from the iTunes Store is limited to the iTunes application. You can use a link which will pass the user to iTunes to look at that particular song but they can't buy it from within your application.

Comment: Ohkay! Thanx Chealion.